# Kiali Dashboard Not able to fetch the k8 namespaces application

Tags: kubernetes, kiali, istio-kiali

I have successfully installed istio and deployed some sample app and application is up and running.

```
root@master:~# kubectl get pod
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mydata-v1-847cd777c4-kc495   2/2     Running   0          39m
mydata-v2-65bbf55977-j67xp   2/2     Running   0          39m
myweb-66dc56ccd6-5g64b       2/2     Running   0          40m
```

```
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
grafana-784c89f4cf-cxpcz                1/1     Running   0          15d
istio-egressgateway-bd477794-qv7n8      1/1     Running   0          15d
istio-ingressgateway-79df7c789f-qlqcf   1/1     Running   0          15d
istiod-6dc55bbdd-t5klg                  1/1     Running   0          15d
jaeger-7f78b6fb65-xhz8j                 1/1     Running   0          15d
kiali-dc84967d9-99lwv                   1/1     Running   1          13d
prometheus-7bfddb8dbf-nd4gn             2/2     Running   35         15d
```

Next i changed kiali dashboard cluster IP to Nodeport to access the dash brad from the browser

```
kubectl patch svc kiali -n istio-system --type='json' -p '[{"op":"replace","path":"/spec/type","value":"NodePort"},{"op":"replace","path":"/spec/ports/0/nodePort","value":30010}]'
```

Finally i can able to access the dashboard using node port with my host Ip http://machineip_port/ and could see my k8 namespaces without any apps please find the attached screen shot

[image: kiali dashboard]

could you please help me someone last one week i am running into this issue.

Comment: Have you tried to change namespace on the top of your dashboard ?

Comment: Yes i changed the name spaces but no use

Comment: Can you please provide all the pod running in istio-system namespace. I hope promethus is running as well.

Comment: Hi Rohit, istio-system ns running pod status updated in above post

Comment: As error is suggesting.. can you please look into namespaces exclusion list.. or try to change the kiali auth from "anonymous" to token. And then try to login using your user token. For exclusion list you can check "kubectl get kiali kiali --all-namespaces" and you auth change check kiali configmap.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

> "Namespaces that do not exist at the time of install but are created
> later in the future will not be accessible by Kiali". [Resource](https://kiali.io/docs/configuration/namespace-management/).

So, first, keep in mind you **should not edit** kiali's ConfigMap, but only Kiali's Custom Resource Definition(CRD), which is used by Kiali Operator.

Run `kubectl edit kiali kiali` in the namespace you have the CRD available.

Then add the following under spec:

```
spec:
  deployment:
    accessible_namespaces:
    - ["**"]
```

This will give Kiali access to all current namespaces and to any you'll create in the future.